# setRenderer() on a grid column broke backend page

Tags: grid, renderer

**Scenario**
I'm overriding a grid and in the `_prepareColumns()` I would like to replace a column renderer with custom one.

Because the column already exist I'm using `getColumn()` and the `setRenderer()` method, the issue is that this action is breaking the backend page.

I cannot find any exception/report/log ... so I'm a bit lost.

here the code

```
 protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();
        $this->getColumn('in_products')
            ->setRenderer('MYMODULE/catalog_product_edit_tab_super_config_grid_renderer_checkbox');

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the column is named `in_products`?  Try dumping the value of `$this->getColumn('in_products')` to see whether you're attempting to call `->setRenderer()` on a non-object.

Comment: `in_product` is right, xdebug ..

Comment: Is the path to the custom renderer is correct?

Comment: yes it is correct

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but maybe useful for someone

i have used `setData('renderer', '...') instead of setRenderer('...')`

this is from observer

```
$block->getColumn('column_name')->setData('renderer','MyName_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Grid_Renderer_Denied');
```

and Denied.php

```
<?php
class MyName_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Grid_Renderer_Denied extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        return 'some html here';
    }
}
```